# Is it possible to reconnect a disconnected Linux boot device without rebooting?

Tags: debian, udev, live-usb

I am using a live image of *Debian GNU/Linux* 12.2 (*“bookworm”*; kernel 6.1.0). I booted from a USB memory stick and used the system for several days without problem. Then, upon resuming from standby, it looks like the USB stick had been “disconnected” (not physically) and then connected anew. It now appears as a new device, identified as *“/dev/sdc”* rather than *“sda”*. Remarkably, the system appears to remain broadly functional, in the sense that already-running software continues to run, and previously-loaded-then-terminated software can be run again, without issue. On the other hand, it looks like files on the root file system that have never been read (since the session started) cannot be accessed (however, my assessment could be simplistic or wrong). A simple remedy would be to restart the system but, for various reasons, I would like to keep this session going for a few days longer before doing so.

Assuming that my limited understanding of the situation is not entirely wrong (I’d be grateful for corrections), I have two questions:

1. Is it possible, without restarting the system, to restore initial and full functionality? Perhaps by getting the boot USB stick device to be seen as *“sda”* again and remounting all file systems? (But I don’t know how to do that.)
2. Why is the system still running (rather than crashed)? That is, why are previously-accessed files still accessible? Is this merely a side-benefit of file-system caching (i.e., if more files are read, the cache gets full and old entries get kicked out, I will suddenly lose the ability to access those now-purged files)? Or is there some other reason, perhaps linked to the way the *“iso9660”* and *“overlay”* file systems are handled, perhaps one that might make my situation somewhat less precarious?